# user defined function for xquery if else condition

Tags: xquery

My code is working fine if I don't use function.

```
declare function local:samlefamily(
$pers as xs:string?) as xs:string?
{
some stuff
};

if (exists(/*/FamilyRec/Child/Link[@Ref = "IN0099"])) 
then 
  for $family in doc("family.xml") /*/FamilyRec
  where $family/Child/Link[@Ref = "IN0099"]
  return if (local:samlefamily(data($family/HusbFath/Link/@Ref))) then local:samlefamily(data($family/HusbFath/Link/@Ref)) else "na1"  
else "na2"
```

But problem occurs when I tried to define function

```
declare function local:giveParent($pers as xs:string) as xs:string
{if (exists(/*/FamilyRec/Child/Link[@Ref = $pers])) 
then 
  for $family in doc("gedcom.xml") /*/FamilyRec
  where $family/Child/Link[@Ref = $pers]
  return if (local:samlefamily(data($family/HusbFath/Link/@Ref))) then local:samlefamily(data($family/HusbFath/Link/@Ref)) else "na1"  
else "na2"
};
```

I am getting error: 
Description: Unexpected token "< eof >" in path expression

It is not occurring for passing parameter($pers). Even I use static ("IN0099") parameter to it, same error I am getting.
Can anyone please help? Can't I use If ... else in user defined function? Advanced thanks for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have at least one non-function statement in the xquery file, i.e. add anything after the last semicolon

Otherwise your code looks fine